# Merging tags [ecommerce] and [e-commerce]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [ecommerce](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce) and [e-commerce](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) tags refer to the same thing and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [ecommerce](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce)
Qs tagged [e-commerce](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `e-commerce` > `ecommerce`